# How to bind a XAML datatemplate to the pages ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a datatemplate for a treeview where i want to introduce a checkbox functionality for favoriting the items in the treeview by executing a simple function in my ViewModel.

However, I can't seem to bind the command function of the checkbox to the ViewModel while still retaining the datatype of the datatemplate.

My datatemplate for the items in the threeview looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:FamilyItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Margin="0 4 0 4" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding FamImage}" Width="125" Height="125"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ToolTip="{Binding Path}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" />

                    <!---FIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIX-->
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFavorite}" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ModelFamilyPage}}, Path=DataContext.FavoriteChckboxCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

The model FamilyItem inherits from a model called 'item' that looks like this:

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public InteropBitmap FamImage { get; set; }
        public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
        public bool IsFile { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried using the RelativeSource that people are suggesting on several forum posts, but without luck.
The data context of the page is set to the correct ViewModel and is working properly for the rest of my functions.